# How to use a Countries look up table in an Address table. EF Core

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm attempting to create an Address table which will contain a Country entity.
The Address table can only contain 1 Country entry. I'd like to have another table which contains a list of countries. On the UI I want a drop down list which will list all of the countries (which reside in the Countries table). When a country is selected, the Country entity in the Address table will be populated.

I'm unsure about the relationship between the Address table and the Country table. It seems to me that the Countries table is not a dependent table (stand alone).

I'm unsure how to annotate my properties to get the desired result.

Currently this is what my Address model looks like.

```
public class Address
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 255 )]
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [MaxLength( 50 )]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public Country Country { get; set; }
}
```

And the Country model.

```
public class Country
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated( DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity )]
    public int CountryId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    public Address Address { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey( nameof( AddressId ) )]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
}
```

And the context

```
public sealed class LodgingCrmContext : DbContext
{
    public LodgingCrmContext( DbContextOptions<LodgingCrmContext> options ) 
        : base( options )
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }   
}
```

The Address FK and the Address navigation property in the Country model makes no sense to me. You wouldn't navigate from a country to an address. Furthermore the Countries table should be a standalone table, not dependent on the Address table. How can I accomplish this?

I'm a little confused and could use some help.

Comment: Try reading and you may be able to get more knowledge in EF relationships
http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-one-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx

Comment: I have, and I already looked through the site you posted as well. Thanks for your help

Comment: You may need to look into ForeignKey and its placements in the right object.

You are almost there otherwise

Comment: One country can be referenced in more addresses. So consider removing your Address Field there too

Comment: It seems to me that the Address entity should contain only a CountryId field. The FK and the navigation property in the Country entity should be removed. So, when an address is being filled out on the form the user will select their country of origin from a drop down list. On submit, the country Id will be entered in to the Address entities CountryId field. Does this sound about right? This way the Countries table will not be a dependent table.

Comment: The relationship between the Address table and the Country table is `many-to-one`. Simply remove `Address` and `AddressId` properties from `Country
` class and you are done. You could add explicit FK property `CountryId` to `Address` class, but it's not strongly necessary. See [Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships).

Comment: By convention, the Countries will become a dependent table if I use the Country entity in the Address entity. Correct me if I'm wrong, but that means the Countries table depends on the Address table. Without an Address, there is no Country. But I want the Countries table to be a fully populated table filled with country names. The Countries table is a lookup table. So, it seems like the Address entity should only contain a CountryId property which can be used to find the country in the Countries table.

Comment: No. See my previous comment. By convention the `many` side is the dependent. Having `Country` *reference* navigation property in `Address` is the same as having *collection* navigation property `public ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }` in `Country`.

Comment: Ivan Stoev is correct. If you want to know more about configuring EF relationships in Core, have a look at this: http://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/relationships. It features Authors and Books, where Authors equates to Countries and Books to Addresses.